# WooCommerce redirects to My Account not to Checkout after Sign Up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this functions.php code so when my clients want to check out they will redirect to Sign up or log in before they checkout, I tried this method below but after all it does not redirect to Checkout page but to My Account, any idea on how to fix the code so I will be redirected to Checkout and not to My Account.

```
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in()
{
    $pageid = 68; // your checkout page id
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
    {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url('/my-account/') // your my acount url
        );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: So when the client Sign up it does not redirect to the Checkout but to My Account , i want when they finish sign up to redirect to checkout !

Answer (score 0):

Try using this filter: `woocommerce_registration_redirect`

```
    function woocommerce_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
        return wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' );
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'woocommerce_register_redirect' );
```